# Back button closing app instead of going back on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've created a simple Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013 and added 2 Basic Pages, along with some code to navigate to the second screen when a button on the first screen is clicked. Going to the second screen works fine, but when the hardware Back button is pressed, the app simply closes. I want the app to go back to the first page when the Back button is pressed.

I have followed the instructions in `NavigationHelper.vb` and added a `Sub New()` with some initialization commands, but the Back button still does not work. How can I get pressing Back to work correctly? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

`BasicPage1.xaml.vb`:

```
Imports App1.Common

Public NotInheritable Class BasicPage1
    Inherits Page

    Private WithEvents _navigationHelper As New NavigationHelper(Me)
    Private ReadOnly _defaultViewModel As New ObservableDictionary()

    Public ReadOnly Property NavigationHelper As NavigationHelper
        Get
            Return _navigationHelper
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        Me._navigationHelper = New Common.NavigationHelper(Me)
        AddHandler Me._navigationHelper.LoadState, AddressOf NavigationHelper_LoadState
        AddHandler Me._navigationHelper.SaveState, AddressOf NavigationHelper_SaveState
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property DefaultViewModel As ObservableDictionary
        Get
            Return _defaultViewModel
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub NavigationHelper_LoadState(sender As Object, e As LoadStateEventArgs) Handles _navigationHelper.LoadState
    End Sub

    Private Sub NavigationHelper_SaveState(sender As Object, e As SaveStateEventArgs) Handles _navigationHelper.SaveState
    End Sub

#Region "NavigationHelper registration"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
        _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As NavigationEventArgs)
        _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e)
    End Sub

#End Region

    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        Frame.Navigate(GetType(BasicPage2))
    End Sub
End Class
```

`BasicPage2.xaml.vb`:

```
Imports App1.Common

Public NotInheritable Class BasicPage2
    Inherits Page

    Private WithEvents _navigationHelper As New NavigationHelper(Me)
    Private ReadOnly _defaultViewModel As New ObservableDictionary()

    Public ReadOnly Property NavigationHelper As NavigationHelper
        Get
            Return _navigationHelper
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        Me._navigationHelper = New Common.NavigationHelper(Me)
        AddHandler Me._navigationHelper.LoadState, AddressOf NavigationHelper_LoadState
        AddHandler Me._navigationHelper.SaveState, AddressOf NavigationHelper_SaveState
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property DefaultViewModel As ObservableDictionary
        Get
            Return _defaultViewModel
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub NavigationHelper_LoadState(sender As Object, e As LoadStateEventArgs) Handles _navigationHelper.LoadState
    End Sub

    Private Sub NavigationHelper_SaveState(sender As Object, e As SaveStateEventArgs) Handles _navigationHelper.SaveState
    End Sub

#Region "NavigationHelper registration"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
        _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As NavigationEventArgs)
        _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e)
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

The full solution is here: https://github.com/OrangeFlash81/SimpleWPApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself by adding an event handler using `AddHandler` and using `Frame.Navigate` to go back to the first page. I added this code:

```
Sub New()
    AddHandler HardwareButtons.BackPressed, AddressOf BackPressed
End Sub

Sub BackPressed(sender As Object, e As BackPressedEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True
    Frame.Navigate(GetType(BasicPage1))
End Sub
```